# Freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected collection or sequence

Tags: json, freemarker

I am trying to print the `json` data in the freemarker html template. But getting below exception:

> freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected collection or
>   sequence. results.completedJobs evaluated instead to
>   freemarker.ext.beans.StringModel on line 23, column 8 in
>   JobTrackingTemplate.ftl. at
>   freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:136)

```
***********************************************************************
        import org.json.JSONObject;
    import freemarker.template.Configuration;
    import freemarker.template.Template;
    import freemarker.template.TemplateException;
    import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;


            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(templatesFolder));
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);


            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("test.ftl");

                     Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();



             String json="{\"completedJobs\":[{\"completedTime\":\"Sat Jan 23 13:17:30 IST 2016\"}]"
                    + ",\"PendingJobs\":[],\"failedJobs\":[]}";
             JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json);


            jsonObject.put("todaysdate", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            model.put("results", jsonObject);


            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
            template.process(model, out);
```

---

```
        test.ftl
        ***********

        <html>
<head>Tracking Data - ${results.todaysdate}</head>
<body>

<h1>Allocated</h1>

<table border=2>
<tr>
    <td><B>time</B></td>


</tr>

<#list results.completedJobs as key>
    ${key.completedTime}

</#list>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`results.completedJobs` will call `JSONObject.get("completedJobs")`, as FreeMarker knows the `get(key)` convention. The result of that is a `JSONArray`. But that doesn't implement `List` or anything familiar, so FreeMarker doesn't know how to list it. If you extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` (or whatever object wrapper you are using) so that it wraps `JSONArray`-s into a `TemplateSquenceModel`-s, and then use `Configuration.setObjectWrapper(yourCustomObjectWrapper)`, then you will be able to list it. Or, you can do this, but it's not very nice:

```
<#assign completedJobs = results.completedJobs>
<#list 0 ..< completedJobs.length() as i>
  ${completedJobs.get(i).completedTime}
</#list>
```

But, if you are using an old FreeMarker, it won't know `..<`. You should upgrade anyway (I see from the error message that it's a somewhat old version).